# Kotlin Android - saving mutableMap in savedInstanceState?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin-android-extensions, android-savedstate

Is there a way to save map/mutableMap into savedInstanceState?

other than using ViewModel functions. I'm curious to know his point...

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked on it. wonder why i didn't find anyone asking about this before, probably there are better ways. but in case that someone needs to know how this is done. i did it this way...

i used onSaveInstanceState to check if the map was initialized, then proceeded

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
        if (::answersMap.isInitialized){
            val keys = (answersMap.keys).toIntArray()
            val values = (answersMap.values).toBooleanArray()
            savedInstanceState.putIntArray(KEYS, keys)
            savedInstanceState.putBooleanArray(VALUE, values)
        }
    }
```

also on the onCreate function I retrieved the arrays and created the mutablemap i needed

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val keysArray = savedInstanceState?.getIntArray(KEYS) ?: IntArray(0)
        val valuesArray = savedInstanceState?.getBooleanArray(VALUE) ?: BooleanArray(0)
        answersMap = mutableMapOf<Int, Boolean>().apply {
            for (i in keysArray.indices) this [keysArray[i]] = valuesArray[i]
        }
```

in case you were wondering about the answerMap type

```
private lateinit var answersMap : MutableMap<Int, Boolean>
```

IT WORKED!!!